# Word for presenting facts, but also being at pains to not infer anything beyond those facts

Tags: vocabulary

"They only stated heavily ???? facts"

They were careful to only state facts and were even at pains to explicitly clarify that those facts did not imply other things that people might usually infer.   AKA, they were scared of getting sued.

Closest I can think of is 'clarified' or 'tempered' but I think there must be better.

Comment: “Bare facts” is a common phrase to express facts only, without obvious implications. There’s no implication here that the speaker is trying to avoid legal consequences, though.

Comment: Do you think the term 'self-explanatory' will work?

Comment: Heavily “edited (or “redacted”) facts. You’re referring to facts carefully worded in order to avoid getting in trouble, germane or not. And in a story it’s best to avoid “germane” and other officialese.

Comment: Facts are facts, not usually "heavily-qualified". So ***They only issued heavily-quaiified statements*** is probably what you meant.

Comment: They are pussyfooting around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple basic statement “They stated facts” is qualified by the adverbs *only* and *heavily* (which adds a note of emphasis).

The restriction of the implications of the facts or of the inferences to be drawn from them is mainly achieved by the use of *only* rather than by the choice of adjective for *facts*.

The choice of adjective must therefore at least be consistent with, and perhaps reinforce, that restriction. Among others, I consequently suggest adjectives such as *proven*, *plain*, *incontrovertible*, *bare*.

> unembellished: lacking embellishment or elaboration (as with decorative elements or fanciful details) : not embellished. "a plain, unembellished room", "
> unembellished facts"
>
> incontrovertible: not open to question : indisputable
>
> plain: : lacking ornament, undecorated, free of extraneous matter, pure
>
> bare:  having nothing left over or added
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/)

These adjectives are consistent with the facts’ being unembellished, not misleading, legally demonstrable, uncoloured by subjectivity. This adds to the similar implications of *only*.

Answer (score 1):

- They stated the *unadorned* truth.

> **unadorned** [adjective]
>
> 1. Without addition, decoration, or qualification:
>
> bald, bare, dry, plain, simple, [plain and simple,] unvarnished.

[[The American Heritage® Roget's Thesaurus](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/unadorned)]

> - *We do not expect him to portray the world creatively, but to tell us the unadorned truth about things as they really are.*

[[HelloEnglish.com](https://helloenglish.com/translate/english-indonesian-dictionary/meaning-of-unadorned-in-Indonesian/amp)]

Answer (score 0):

You're making a heavy weather of this. Why not simply say *They only stated facts **germane** to the situation.* If the context however implies that *suing* is a possibility, you'd have to add *lest anyone would misconstrue them.*

> being at once relevant and appropriate : FITTING

*Omit details that are not germane to the discussion.*

[Merriam-Webster]